# jQuery event delegate listener not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, google-chrome-extension, event-delegation

I'm creating a Google Chrome extension and I try to modify Twitter's homepage code for that.

I need to be notified whenever a user clicks on a `--- More` button which are present in every tweet. Basically I use the following event delegation code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function() {
    console.log('Hi !');
});
```

It works for all tweets on the homepage and those loaded via Ajax (that's why I use event delegation :D), but it doesn't work on the sub-tweets/answers that appear when you expand a tweet in the timeline. Yet the menus still have the `dropdown-toggle` class but the callback doesn't get called.

So I though that Twitter's code was calling `event.stopPropagation()` or similar so I tried to remove event listeners on one of them by calling `$(button).off()` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Hi !');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work with tweets loaded via Ajax. That's why I use event delegation.